# Why does tracert not display the IP passing through the router?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router

My computer A (ip: 192.168.50.201) is wirelessly connected to the router, while my computer B (ip: 192.168.50.65) is wired to the router. Why is there only one hop when `tracert 192.168.50.65`, and why is the router's IP not displayed?

```
C:\Users\guoya>tracert 192.168.50.65

通过最多 30 个跃点跟踪
到 GYZ [192.168.50.65] 的路由:

  1     5 ms     2 ms     2 ms  GYZ [192.168.50.65]

跟踪完成。
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't mention the subnet mask, if you check it you'll probably see that both IP addresses are on the same subnet, which specifically means computer A will directly send packets to computer B's MAC address instead of sending them to a gateway's MAC, i.e. no routing will be done.

That works because the router's Wi-Fi interface and its LAN ports are **bridged,** i.e. connected at layer-2 like you would have with an Ethernet switch, so that no routing needs to be done between them. (Indeed the LAN ports are literally an integrated Ethernet switch...)

*[In case you were wondering, unfortunately there is no Ethernet traceroute equivalent.]*

So even though the packets do *physically* pass through the router device, they don't actually pass through its actual "router" component. (For that to happen, computer A would need to address them to the router's MAC address, which it only does for packets that go outside the subnet.)

Practically all home wireless routers are configured this way. They are only called "routers" because originally they had neither Wi-Fi nor LAN switching (i.e. they did *only* IP routing between two ports). Eventually both of those extra features were added for user convenience, but they aren't what makes it a router.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but according to your statement, this problem cannot be explained.   question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769770/customized-linux-system-wired-and-wireless-connectivity-interoperability

Comment: The question you linked is about a different device that doesn't have the same configuration. What you're seeing in *this* thread is not inherent in Wi-Fi or multi-port Ethernet devices – it's *specifically* about the configuration that wireless router manufacturers set up. When you're customizing your own network equipment from scratch, that does not apply.